# Dynamically Change Watch Directories for Inotify

Tags: linux, bash, centos-7, globbing, inotify

Thanks for any help in advance!

I have set up an inotifywait script to monitor some applications for configuration changes.  I am globbing to create all of the directories to watch; however, if there is a new application deployed, it is not picked up by the glob.

```
inotifywait -m -e close_write,delete /apps/*/etc |
while read eventdir eventlist eventfile
do
    # do work
done
```

The issues is that when there is a new app deployed to `/apps`, the glob which `inotifywait` is watching, does not include `/apps/new_app/etc/`.  Is there any way to dynamically update this glob or accomplish the same goal?

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an amazing way to do this.  What I ended up doing is creating a second script which monitors for new applications in `/apps/`.  When this sees a new application, it restarts the script in the question so that it has accurate file globs

Answer (score 0):

```
inotifywait -mr -e close_write,delete /apps/*/etc |
```

while read eventdir eventlist eventfile
do
    # do work
done

Add -r flag for recursive

Answer (score 0):

Ingredients:

- `man inotifywait` tells us that the watchlist can be supplied with `--fromfile <watchlist-file>`
- The command `entr` can trigger a utility based on modifications to any given file

To solve your problem using the above info:

1. Put all directories to be watched in a file, say `WATCHLIST=/tmp/watchlist`
2. Replace `inotify` in the pipeline you posted with: `entr -ar inotifywait -m -e close_write,delete --fromfile /_ <<< "${WATCHLIST}"`
3. Modify the watchlist file as neccessary - append new folders to be watched or delete/edit existing ones with `sed -i <cmd> "${WATCHLIST}"`